# Request dependent concrete factory in .NET 6.0 Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, abstract-factory

Lets say I have two factories that are producing very similar sets of products.
This is a typical case where I use an abstract factory in my app:

[image]

This is a very simplified version of my scenario.

Now the thing is, that my factories have many dependencies. I would like to add those dependencies via dependency injection to the factory.

So I am creating my factories also via DI like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IAbstractFactory, ConcreteFactory1>();    
services.AddScoped<IAbstractFactory, ConcreteFactory2>();
```

Of course this must fail. The DI engine does not know which concrete factory to inject.

This depends on a parameter of my API request and can change for each request.

So for some requests my DI should deliver ConcreteFactory1, and for other requests ConcreteFactory2.

How can I archive this?

Comment: Consider using the `AddScoped<T>()` overload that takes a `Func<IServiceProvider, T>`. You can then run code when the dependency is resolved to choose which concrete implementation to select. Those can then be registered as themselves using `AddScoped<ConcreteFactory1>()` etc. and also retrieved from the `IServiceProvider` and returned to the caller.

Comment: This works! I tried it.

Comment: Ah: var context = func.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();